# How to read contact details sent from iphone?

Tags: mms, ios, vcard

When someone with an iPhone sends me a contact, it appears as a blank MMS message. I found that this happens because group chat is on on their end, but these people are not always my friends, so I can't tell them to turn it off.

Is there a way to read these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Some Android devices does not have support for handling MMS or SMS vCards in their native texting app. That is why you see it as "content not supported" or even blank message.

You can use third pardy app to handle MMS vCards if your Android device does not support it by default too. Search on Google Play. I've created such an app [bizCard Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mrpear.vcardmanager). There are plenty more that handle SMS vCards but I've not found any that has MMS support.

Answer (score -2):

Try Textra. This texting app also allowed me to import vcards in existing messages.